# Backbone click event fires events for all collection rather than model

Tags: events, backbone.js

Can't figure out what's wrong. When I click on a model title, it fetches all models in collection at once rather than fetch one model. If I move this event from logView to logsView it works properly but doesn't have access to model, well I can find this model using index or ant other model's ID but don't think this is a nice way.

```
var Log = Backbone.Model.extend({});


window.LogsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Log,

    url:function (tag) {
        this.url = '/logs/' + tag;
        return this;
    }
});

window.colList = new LogsList();

window.logView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('.accordion'),

    template:_.template($('#log').html()),

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind('add', this.render, this);
    },

    events:{
        "click .accordion-toggle" :"getLogBody"
    },

    render:function () {
        return this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    },

    getLogBody:function () {
        this.model.fetch();
    }
});

window.LogsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#content"),

    initialize:function (options) {
        colList.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
        colList.url(options.data).fetch();
    },

    addOne:function (model) {
        var view = new logView({model:model});
        $("#accordion").append(view.render());
    },

    addAll:function () {
        colList.each(this.addOne);
    }
});

window.listView = new LogsView({data:"Visa_Cl"});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is caused by your `el` in the LogView: `el:$('.accordion')`

Backbone's view events are scope to the view's `el`. In this case, you've specified the view's `el` as **ALL** HTML elements with a class of "accordion". Therefore, when you click on *any* of your HTML elements with this class, the code runs for all of them, which is why you are seeing this behavior.

This article will show you a few options for doing what you want, correctly:

- [Backbone.js: Getting The Model For A Clicked Element](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/)

I would also recommend reading this one, to better understand the use of `el` in Backbone, and a few of the tricks and traps of it:

- [Backbone.js: Object Literals, Views Events, jQuery, and `el`](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that I messed with it.